# Moving files to mounted drive

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, mount

On an Ubuntu server (16.04) I have the following mounted drives (`df -h`):

[image]

I had a big file in my home directory and I ran the following command:

```
sudo mv Miras.txt /dev/sda3
```

It took time and apperently moved the files

However when I ran `cd /dev/sda3`, it says:

```
-bash: cd: /dev/sda3: Not a directory
```

I noticed its mounted as `/drive2`, but then again there is not my file on `/drive2` either.

Where was my filed moved, and how can I access it?

Comment: Try `whereis Miras.txt`

Comment: You should reference the mount point `/drive2`, not the device. And don't use sudo for moving private files

Comment: you have moved and renamed your file as sda3. revert by sudo mv /dev/sda3 miras.txt.

Comment: @Ajay there was probably a file named `/dev/sda3` which could be related to the mounted drive. Doesn't this replacement make problem for it?

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is that you have moved your file and renamed it as sda3. so to revert open terminal at same location where you earlier opened it and run:

```
sudo mv /dev/sda3 miras.txt
```

/dev/sda3 was a special node file that would otherwise be used to mount your USB disk. But you have replaced it with a *.txt file.

As your miras.txt file was in Home folder you no need to use `sudo` at all. If you run your `mv` command without `sudo` it will show "Permission denied".

Now unplug and replug-in sda3 if it was a USB stick otherwise you can use:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda3

sudo mount /dev/sda3
```

Otherwise you can just restart the system. Linux will automatically recreate the device special /dev/sda3 if necessary.